# Selecting an element which has another element as direct child

Tags: jquery

I need to select all `div`s which contain `object` as their direct child. `:has` just checks for descendants of any kind, so now I'm using:

```
$('div > object').parent().css('text-align', 'center');
```

is there a more direct way?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can simplify your code to:

```
$('div:has(> object)').css('text-align', 'center');
```

Comment: The selector `$("whatever_1:has(> whatever_2)")` works to filter by direct child. `$("whatever_1").has("> whatever_2")` does not. The two techniques are _not_ equivalent.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's a Nobel price somewhere in Norway waiting for the person who invented jQuery to pick it up. I freakin' love jQuery!

Comment: @Zarepheth why not?

Answer (score 9):

Use the [`:has`](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) selector:

```
$("div:has(> object)").css("text-align", "center");
```

Here's an example I wrote up:

```js
$(function() {
  $("div:has(> h3)").css("background", "yellow");
});
```

```css
div { padding: 15px; border: 1px solid black; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <h2>outer</h2>
  <div>
    <h3>inner</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```