# jQuery selector for sibling of a label in a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm writing a user-script for a third-party website and looking to select value inside a table which has a preceding `TD` with a label.

**Question**: I'm looking to get `value1` as the result, but it's selecting the containing `TD` as well, so I get `something else` too.

**Limitations**

- Can't modify the HTML to be more query-friendly (duh, it's not my site ;)
- The table has **no ids** (I added them for easier discussion), not even the `<table>` itself has an id.
- The count of the rows is dynamic, so **no `tr:nth-child`**.

**Tried**
I found this question: [Selecting an element which has another element as direct child](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2243369/253468) and used the direct selector (`tr:has(> td:contains`), but it still selects more than needed, because the `outer` `TD` also transitively contains `label1` and has a sibling.

*Notice that the background I set is transparent to show that multiple `TD`s are selected.*

```js
$(function() {
  $('#result').text($('tr:has(td:contains("label1")) > td:nth-child(2)').text())
  $('tr:has(td:contains("label1"))').css("background", "rgba(255,0,0,0.3)");
});
```

```css
table { border-collapse: collapse; }
table, th, td { border: 1px solid black; }
td { padding: 4px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="outer">
      <table>
        <tr><td id="known-info">label1</td><td id="want-to-select">value1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>label2</td><td>value2</td></tr>
      </table>
    </td>
    <td id="outer-sibling">something else</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br/>
This should be "value1": "<span id="result"></span>"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `:not(:has(td))` in your selector so it should be

```
$('td:contains("label1"):not(:has(td))').next().text()
```

This will select `td` that contains `label1` text, but it will ignore parent `td` because it has another `td` inside.

```js
var el = $('td:contains("label1"):not(:has(td))').next()
$('#result').text(el.text())
el.css('background', 'blue')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="outer">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td id="known-info">label1</td>
          <td id="want-to-select">value1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>label2</td>
          <td>value2</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
    <td id="outer-sibling">something else</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br/> This should be "value1": "<span id="result"></span>"
```

Comment: Good idea, thank you! Also thanks for bringing my attention to `.next()` it's better than `nth-child(2)` in this particular case. Are you aware of `:next` or similar selector (neither `~`, nor `+` help here AFAIK)?

Comment: You could use `+` https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/2144/, and i am not aware of `:next`.

Comment: @TWiStErRob: Yeah, `$('td:contains("label1"):not(:has(td)) + td')` would also work. For a full list, of course, there's [the jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com) and [the CSS selectors spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/).